# How to update Large table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to update a large number of rows (more than 80k) from an external data source (from file) into an existing mysql table. This database is InnoDB.

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `job_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `client_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `department` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `job_order` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `completion_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `achivement_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `achivement_value` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `current_status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `supervisor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `job_no` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Update QUERY

```
UPDATE jobs SET job_date='$job_date',client_code='$value[1]',department='$value[2]',job_order='$job_order',completion_date='$completion_date',achivement_date='$achivement_date',achivement_value='$achivement_value',current_status='$value[7]',supervisor='$value[8]' WHERE job_no='$value[9]
```

How to optimize this query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **job_no** is unique it could be much faster (adding a unique index to the job_no). but even if its not unique this query could be optimized just adding an index to the **job_no**

`ALTER TABLE jobs
ADD INDEX ind_job_no (job_no) USING BTREE;`

adding this index will allow you to update quicker.